# Muti level domains with Facebook App

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

We run a web application that serves multiple top level domains. We are currently trying to authenticate users through OAuth (Google, Facebook, Twitter).

The initial problem we had was that Google did not support access to multiple top level domains. To get around this we proxy the traffic through one top level domain and it just acts as an intermediary that forwards requests on to the oAuth providers and the callback to our different top level domains. This all works fine for google but does not when it comes to facebook.

The Facbook one does something a bit different that it checks to see if the current url your on is a) Is in the app domains ? b) Is it the same redirect uri used when the initial OAuth Dialog was requested?

Our flow is like this.

**Request Permission**
Top Level Domain -> Proxy -> Facebook OAuth

**Callback**
Facebook OAuth -> Proxy -> Top Level Domain

Because the redirect url is set to the Proxy URL when the user allows permission, i cannot get any information from the api using the initial top level domain.

The Exception produced is: {"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}

Anyone have ANY clue how to get around this?

Comment: You will have to do the exchange of the code for an access token via your proxy domain as well.

Comment: That's where I am stuck. The base facebook class uses the current url (getCurrentUrl()) rather than the overridden url for this. So whenever I try to exchange the code for a token it uses my top level domain. Then throws an exception with the conflict in domains. I could just change the base facebook function to suit my liking but not sure if it's the right thing to do. :p

Answer (score 0):

The PHP SDK lets you pass in an alternative redirect_uri:

```
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'redirect_uri' => '{TLD URL}', 'scope' => '{SCOPE}' ) );
```

The Facebook App Settings page also lets you set multiple domains or subdomains to use with your application, so make sure your base domains are all added to the Settings Page (under `App Domains`).

Using these two methods should resolve the issue for you.